# How to start_activity with intent of opening a url with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am trying to open a Facebook post URL in the FB app. But Android is asking me to choose with which app to open the URL and ask me "Only once?" or "Always?".
I clicked always but it still doesn't open the FB app. I am stocked here.

**EDIT:**

These screenshots are showing what is going on on smartphones and tried all the scenarios possible by hand and by script. It still doesn't want to open the URL in the app:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I did some search about this issue and I discovered that the method "start_activity" has some parameters "intent":
https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

The problem is that this parameter is only for java and doesn't exist for Python, does it?

Does anyone know how can I open FB app on a particular post with the help of the URL post?

Comment: Can you please share the github link to your repo so that the corresponding issue can be reproduced & identified. I tried with a random fb url using java client with method `driver.get()` and it was working fine as expected. `Appium v1.22.2` & `java-client v8.1.1`

Comment: Thank you @BipinKumarChaurasia for helping me. I added some screenshots to show you what is going on. I don't think you need more code as the issue is the same by hands. I edit the URL to transform it as https://m.facebook.com/..... with a m.facebook.com but it didn't change.